# Checking the convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

this is  one of many series that I have to check whether it converges or diverges. and to also check absolute convergence if possible:

$$\sum{\frac{e^\sqrt[3]{n}}{n^{\log ~ n} + 1}}$$

I don't know how to even start with this one,
please any help?

Comment: Is $\log n$ at the exponent?

Comment: yes that's what I meant

Answer (score 4):

Edit: We know that $n^{\log(n)}=e^{\log^2(n)}$. Hence:
$$\dfrac{e^{\sqrt[3]{n}}}{n^{\log(n)}+1}=\dfrac{e^{n^{1/3}}}{e^{\log^2(n)}+1}= e^{n^{1/3}-\log^2(n)}\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-\log^2(n)}}\longrightarrow\infty$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$. The series must diverge since the general term tends to infinity.

Comment: i'm sorry if my notation was bad,

Comment: but it's n^log n